# Set variable equal to return data from an async function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I have a function that has asynchronous tasks in it

```
function getDroplets(key) {
    return getRequest('https://api.digitalocean.com/v2/droplets', key).then(function(response) {
        var droplets = response.droplets;
        var numDroplets = droplets.length;
        return {
            data: response,
            droplets: droplets,
            numDroplets: numDroplets
        }
    });
}
```

I want to take the return data from this function and store it in a variable named dropletData. But, I currently am getting undefined.

```
var dropletData = async(key) => {
    data = await getDroplets(key);
    return data;
};

dropletData = dropletData(api_key);
```

Comment: `dropletData(api_key).then(result => ...)` or `const result = dropletData(api_key)`

Comment: Since `dropletData` is `async`, *its caller* will have to `await` *it* as well.

Comment: And `data` should not be global...

Comment: 1) Don't overwrite your function `dropletData` with the value `dropletData` 2) use `dropletData = await getDroplets(api_key)` - and put all the code that uses the variable into that `async function` where it can wait

Comment: @JonasW. for the first one, could you complete the arrow function?

Comment: @JonasW. I have this so far, but it doesn't work `var dropletData = () => getDroplets(api_key).then(response => response);`

Comment: Don't try to turn something asynchronous into a synchronous thing. Thats like trying to read the newspaper of tomorrow. It just does not work.